# Как проверить 3 input сразу?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Почему то у меня проверяет только один `input` вместо каждого с `name=one`. Кто может подсказать как сделать проверку каждого `input name="one"` ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inputRequired = $( "input[name='one']" );
  
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    if( !inputRequired.val() ) {
        console.log("Error");
        $(this).parent().find("input[name='one']").val("").addClass('error');
    } else {
        console.log("OK!");
    }
  })
  
});
```

```css
input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input class="date" type="text" name="one" >  
  <input class="name" type="text" name="one" >
  <input class="money" type="text" name="one" >
  <input class="price" type="text" >

  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: если у вас селектор возвращает массив, и проверить надо каждый. то и используйте для этого цикл ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Значение каждого `input`-а можно проверять отдельно с помощью метода [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/). Либо можно сразу отфильтровать `input`-ы с некорректными значениями с помощью метода [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)
- Класс `error`, надо полагать, нужно добавлять только тем `input`-ам, у которых некорректное значение
- Также класс `error` стоит убирать у тех элементов, значение которых стало валидным

В итоге получается так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $inputsRequired = $("input[name='one']");

  $("button").on("click", function() {
    $inputsRequired.removeClass("error");
    var $incorrectInputs = $inputsRequired.filter(function() {
        return this.value == "";
    });
    if ($incorrectInputs.length != 0) {
      console.log("Error");
      $incorrectInputs.val("").addClass("error");
    }
    else {
      console.log("OK!");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
button {
  display: flex;
  margin: 5px;
}
.error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input class="date" type="text" name="one">
  <input class="name" type="text" name="one">
  <input class="money" type="text" name="one">
  <input class="price" type="text">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А можно обойтись без `each` так как у меня непростая структура, пример просто для понимания вопроса?

Comment: @max А как вы себе представляете получение данных из нескольких объектов?

Comment: @max что такое "непростая структура", и как `each` вместо `val` что-то усложняет?

Comment: Мне не нужно значение, а только проверить пусто или нет. Думал можно по клику смотреть каждый `element.val()`, если хотя бы в одном пусто, делать ошибку

Comment: Я понял в чем суть, `each` - ом можно проходить по любым элементам, в любом месте страницы, так ведь?

Comment: @max функция `each` в данной ситуации применяется к конкретной коллекции элементов `$("input[name='one']")`. Вы можете её применять к любой коллекции. Если строго говоря, то к любому `jQuery`-объекту.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var inputRequired = $( "[name = 'one']" );

  $('button').on('click', function() {
    if( !inputRequired.val() ) {
        console.log("Error");
        $(this).parent().find("[name = 'one']").val("").addClass('error');
    } else {
        console.log("OK!");
    }
  });

});
```

Также более современно будет использовать вместо:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  // Ваш код
});
```

Это:

```
$(function() {
  // Ваш код
});
```

Comment: 1. Что несовременного в `$(document).ready`? Да, вариант длиннее, но он не deprecated и более нагляден. 2. Вы проверяли свой код на работоспособность? Вроде это современно - проверять на наличие ошибок. В частности, проверка `input`-ов по отдельности у вас не работает.